# TextureView and Transparency

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, textureview

I have a TextureView with a mediaPlayer attached to it, so i can use its surface to display a video, so far it's working well.
Now i try to create a fade in animation for displaying the video and i have no clue of how to do it.

I tried with the setOpaque(false) setting and playing with the alpha setting but it doesn't have any effects.
Also i tried the textureView without a mediaPlayer and i notice that i can't change the background color either, it's always black.
The documentation say that the behaviour of this view is the same as the standard view, but it doesn't seem to be the case.
Does anyone know how to change the transparency of this view ?

Thanks

Comment: Hi there. Did you get a solution to this. This is exactly what I have been looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem, and you just need to set setAlpha(0.999f) and it will have transparent background.

Comment: The Alpha Level might be different for different devices. It didn't work for me with 0.999f, but it did with 0.995f.